# Is there a Spy++ like utility for WPF?

Tags: wpf, utilities, spy++

As a “hardcore” WinForms programmer from a Win32 background I have always used [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242713(VS.60).aspx) to understand what my applications are doing at the UI level including:

- Seeing what **events** the controls are sending to each other.
- Seeing the **control tree** at run time
- Finding the control that is **drawing part of the display**

I then often search for the **control name** in the source code, very useful when you have to change the UI on a large application you don’t know well.

So how do I do the same with a **WPF** application?

*(You may assume I have access to the source code of the WPF application if needed, however I rather the utility worked without the need for the applications source code.)*

---

Thanks for the answers, I have just searched for “[Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/)” in StackOverflow and found a few questions/answers with lists of WPF tools.

- [What tools do you use for WPF development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642/what-tools-do-you-use-for-wpf-development)
- [Tools to develop WPF or Silverlight applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189244/tools-to-develop-wpf-or-silverlight-applications)
- [How to speed up WPF programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222070/how-to-speed-up-wpf-programs) - has a list of related tools

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf). It is exactly like Spy++ for WPF.

[image]

Comment: ++ Snoop's my favourite too. There's others, but they aren't as good as snoop. If you're programming silverlight then there's Silverlight Spy: http://silverlightspy.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/

Comment: Snoop is totally awesome. +1 I also want to point anyone who looks at this question/answer to effort I've done with Snoop at http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com.

I have added interop support, 64-bit support, WPF 4.0 support and more. See my blog for more info too: http://www.cplotts.com/2009/12/08/snoop-now-with-64-bit-support-and-more/

Answer (score 5):

***Note: Present post is based on Web Archive, and the original page is not currently available as of 2018/07/12!***

I prefer Snoop, but also wanted to point out [Mole](https://web.archive.org/web/20080201111422/http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/), which is a Visual Studio debugger visualizer for WPF elements:

[image]

Comment: I use Mole. But it doesn't work if you debug a partial trust app (XBAP for example), you have to switch to full trust...

Comment: Someone made it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Oceanware/Mole-Visualizer-For-VS-2019), but source is not open, so i don't like that fact.