# C++ Win32 Design my Window

Tags: c++, winapi, skinning, theming, window-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++/WIN32 A professional looking application - is it really possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717620/c-win32-a-professional-looking-application-is-it-really-possible)

I'm not talking about opening a resource file, (.rc) and make my buttons, and etc ..
I'm talking about the look of the window itself — like the installer for the Visual Studio Ultimate 2012:

[image]

The buttons, and all looks different.  Same with the Photoshop, AE, Maya Autodesk.

How they did it?  Its easy or hard ?  We can do it with c++?

Comment: 1) Don't know, since those programs are not open source 2) Depends on what you are doing 3) probably, but depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: While @Grizzly is right that it's hard to know for sure, check out the answers to the question I linked above...including my [note about Spy++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6717892/211160).  You can probably find some material by browsing the tags for [tag:skinning], [tag:theming], and [tag:window-chrome].

Comment: This is the kind of styling you get out of using XAML.  Not available to C++ programs, except in Windows Store apps.

Comment: That dialog is hideous!  What is with the current obsession with low-contrast text?  I suspect it's a plot against older developers.

Answer (score 0):

C++ I know there is a way to override OS's internal controls rendering, C# for example.
But you can render your controls with [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/). (Create a [GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface))

About If it's hard or easy ,It's hard if you never created projects with [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/).

BTW here is an article in msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183.aspx