# AutoIt with wpf

Tags: wpf, autoit

I have below sample code for my wpf app.
I need to fill in text fields of form with strings.

```
    Run('AutoItWpfTesting.exe')
    WinWaitActive("Window1", "")

    $hHwnd = WinGetHandle("Window1")
    MsgBox(0, "Message", $hHwnd)

   $returnVal1=ControlGetHandle ( "$hHwnd", "", "[NAME:txtVersion]")

   $returnVal2=ControlSend($hHwnd,"","[NAME:txtVersion]","blahblah")

   MsgBox(0, "Message", $returnVal2)
```

it returns 0 for $returnVal2 and Empty string for $returnValue1.
However this works fine for my sample winform application.

Any clues why this behaviour is..and Any tweaks available to get exact text-box to auto fill data for wpfa app.

Answer (score 9):

WPF applications do not use Windows' controls and handles for the controls. You can see that by using Spy++. [WPF Alternatives for Spy++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672696/is-there-a-spy-like-utility-for-wpf)

If you want to automate WPF applications [you will need another tool](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/09153b49-1958-4543-be4f-4ac0fc9a39d1/) or use [the UI Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) to build one.

Comment: This is correct. Aside from that, your $hWnd variable should not be in quotes in the first parameter of the ControlGetHandle call.